# Creating a function using a 'for' loop in R

Tags: r, function, loops, for-loop

I'm just starting to learn R language. I spent half a day on trying to write a function and I'm desperate to find the solution. If someone who is really good could help me and would know what is the solution, thanks a lot :)

So here are the explanations, I have to create a function `f4` that

- takes an input (numeric) vector `v` and an integer `a`,
- and returns the `TRUE` if there are two numbers in `v` that sum up to `a`, and `FALSE` otherwise.
  Note that the answer should include a `for` loop.

Hint: let `i = 1`. If there exist a complementary index `j` such that `v[1] + v[j] == a`, then `f1(v[2:n], a - v[1])` must return `TRUE`. If not, then `v[1]` can be excluded, and one can proceed by looking for the complementary of `v[2]` by checking whether `f1(v[3:n], a - v[2])` returns `TRUE`. This idea can be iterated by written `f4` as a loop over `f1(v[(i+1):n], a - v[i])`.
To check my answer:

The output of `print(sapply(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 20), function(x) f4(1:10, x)))` is :

```
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Here's what I've managed to write for the moment but have been stuck for hours :

```
f4 <- function(v, a) {
  wow <- sort(unique(v))
  m <- outer(wow, wow, "+")
  diag(m) <- 0
  x <- vector("logical", length(a))
  for (i in 1:length(a)) {x[[i]] <- any((m==a[[i]]))}
  print(x)
}
```

I don't know if anyone will be able to help me, but you never know :)

Cheers!

Comment: Not clear about the expected.  What is the expected output

Comment: Do you need `sapply(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 20), function(x) any(outer(1:10, 1:10, `+`) == x))`

Comment: Sorry if I'm not clear enough :) 

I need to create a function such as the output of 'print(sapply(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 20), function(x) f4(1:10, x)))' returns [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE 

whereas so far  the function I have written returns the following output :  
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE
[1] TRUE
[1] TRUE
[1] FALSE
[1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

Comment: Why is the last one `FALSE`.  For me, it returns TRUE `sapply(c(1, 2, 3, 4, 20), function(x) any(outer(1:10, 1:10, `+`) == x))#
[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE`